# Pointer towards making images in UIImageView appear full screen when clicked on

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, fullscreen

I have a UIImageView in my application.  I want to make it so that when you click on the UIImageView, the photo appears full screen as it does when you click on a photo in the Photos app. 
What I want to know is if Apple released an API for doing this - I've seen apps like the wired app do it, where you click on a photo and it goes full screen - what's this called?  So I can research it.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is create a new `UIViewController` that had a `UIImageView` that took up the whole view. I would expose a public property that would allow me to set the image of the `UIImageView`.

Then have your UIImageView respond to a `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event like so: `[imageView addTarget:self action:@selector(imagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Then in `imagePressed:` set the `UIViewController`'s image property, then push the new `UIViewController` onto navigation controller.